# alarms or services for periodic jobs

Tags: android, design-patterns, service, alarm

For an android application that needs some periodic jobs to be done, which is more appropriate solution?

It seems to me that [services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) is the right choice. But I can run periodic jobs with alarms even in background and after rebooting. Should I continue use whichever is easier or stick to one of them in any case?

What are the drawbacks and advantages of the two choices?

In short, I don't want to invent my way but follow the patterns which other android developers follow.

Answer (score 0):

Use service and `AlarmManager`. To continue getting alarms after rebooting subscribe to  `BOOT_COMPLETED` intent (you will need corresponding permission).

Comment: If you don't have service, who will handle your alarm?

Comment: I handle in a simple class derived from BroadcastReceiver class. I don't use IntentService or Service class.